# How to clear DatePicker through binding with SelectedDate

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight

I have a date picker with the following binding.

```
<Controls:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Person.BirthDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearDateOperation}" />
```

This is the class "Person":

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

The initial value of BirthDate is null. 
The issue I want to fix can be reproduced this way:

1. User entered "cvgdfgfg" to the datePicker
2. Clicks the "Clear" button.
3. The datePicker isn't cleared after this.

This is the implementation of ClearDateOperation

```
ClearDateCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClearDate);

private void ClearDate()
        {
            Person.BirthDate = null;
        }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

ps. I use silverlight 4, .NET 4, VS 2010
ps. You can download a simple example with the issue using this link.
[Silverlight app](http://www.filedropper.com/silverlightapplication1)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime? m_BirthDate;

    public DateTime? BirthDate
    { 
     get { return m_BirthDate;}
     set
      { 
         m_BirthDate = value;
         this.OnPropertyChanged("BirthDate");
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did it. But the issue didn't disappear.

Comment: Could you try changing the xaml for your datepicker to bind to text rather than selected date?

Answer (score 0):

```
Person.BirthDate = DateTime.MinDate
```

or somthing like that